# How do I read data from Microsoft Graph API into PowerBI?

Tags: charts, api, microsoft-powerbi

I'm trying to get a list of subscribed users from my tenant using Microsoft Graph API. I've been using the query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscribedSkus which returns the right information on the graph explorer. Then, I found this blog:
https://blog.mydock365.com/microsoft-graph-api-data-on-microsoft-power-bi and followed the steps which said in Power BI go to get data, then OData feed and paste the query in. However, that did not work for me. Please let me know if there is a good way that I can run Microsoft Graph API commands in Power BI.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to consume the output of a REST API, not connect to a database/source.

Looks like this is more what you need -

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charles_sterling/2016/05/25/how-to-call-rest-apis-and-parse-json-with-power-bi/